# Error running SEXTANTE in QGIS on Scientific Linux

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-processing, sextante

I've installed SEXTANTE into qgis on my Scientific Linux machine and I am getting the following when attempting to run Warp;

INFO|Mon Feb 24 2014 15:56:20|GDAL execution console output|/bin/sh: gdalwarp: command not found

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: GDAL seems to not be installed... can you verify?

Comment: Ha! You're right. I have installed lots of other gdal stuff, e.g. devel, gdal-python etc, but not gdal itself. Also, I still couldn't get sextant to work, so I had to downgrade from 1.0.9 to 1.0.8 and it's working fine now.

Comment: Good thing! Welcome to GIS StackExchange by the way !